# Tensorflow Error:ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (656, 875, 3) are not compatible

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf 

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['output/output.tfrecords'])

_,serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features={
    'image_raw':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'height':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'channel':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    })
image = features['image_raw']
height, width = features['height'], features['width']
channel = features['channel']
decoded_image = tf.decode_raw(image, tf.uint8)
decoded_image.set_shape([656, 875, 3])

IMAGE_SIZE = 512
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(decoded_image, dtype=tf.float32)
destorted_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)

min_after_dequeue = 10000
batch_size = 100
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
image_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [destorted_image], batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity = capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    for i in range(10):
        image = sess.run([image_batch])
        print(len(image))
```

I am trying to run the tensorflow to deal my own tfrecords file.  The code :

```
`decoded_image.set_shape([656, 875, 3])`
```

appears the error:ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (656, 875, 3) are not compatible.
if I only run the code:

```
print(sess.run(len(decoded_image)))
```

it's OK, it can show me 1722000.So I think my tfrecords file is no problem.How to deal the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.decode_raw` returns a 1-dimensional tensor, and `tf.set_shape` cannot change the number of dimensions of a tensor.

Instead, use `tf.reshape`, as follows:

```
decoded_image = tf.reshape(decoded_image, shape=[656, 875, 3])
```